# Filtrar las coincidencias dentro de un objeto en Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtro

Tengo un estado en el que guardo un array de string con x cantidad de nombre, puede ser 1 o mas dependiendo de los que seleccione el usuario. Por ejemplo asi :

```
  const [filterRow1, setFilterRow1] = useState([]);
```

Esto es un ejemplo de lo que puedo guardar:

```
['JORGE PADRA', '001', '002', '004']
```

Y por otro lado tengo una variable que esta guardando el nombre de un btn seleccionado:

```
    let btnCol = 'nropedido';
```

Entonces estoy tratando de consultar en mi api solo los values de nro de pedido que coincidan con lo guardado en el estado. Este es mi funcion, donde estuve intentando pero no he logrado aun, si me dan una idea por favor!

```
const getValuesFromColumnsButtons = async (index) => {
    const limitColumn = column.length === 1;
    setIsOpen(true);
    setBtnClick("column");
    let btnCol = "";

    if (limitColumn && row.length === 1 && index === 0) {
      btnCol = ArrayOfSelectedButtons[1];
      const resApi = await getData();
      const queryTheApiWithAllItemsMatchingFilterRow1AndBtnCol = resApi.filter(
        (item) => {
          console.log(item, "item");
          item.includes(filterRow1);
          );
        }
      );
      console.log(queryTheApiWithAllItemsMatchingFilterRow1AndBtnCol);
    } else if (limitColumn && row.length === 2 && index === 0) {
      btnCol = ArrayOfSelectedButtons[2];
    } else {
      alertError("Solo puedes seleccionar 1 opción");
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
  };
```

De hecho me genera este error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: item.includes is not a function
```

Asi luce mi objeto de la Api, es un array de Objetos:

```
[
        {
            "empresa": "63",
            "periodo": "202202",
            "fechaEmision": "03/02/2022",
            "fechaEntrega": "03/02/2022",
            "codJefeVenta": "001",
            "codSupervisor": "001",
            "supervisor": "GUSTAVO CACHAY",
            "codVendedor": "0001",
            "vendedor": "JORGE PADRA",
            "ventasKey": "101000003607",
            "nroPedido": "0010028160",
            "condVenta": "004",
            "codTransporte": null,
            "codCliente": "011296",
            "clieFechaAdd": "03/11/2017",
            "codDirEntrega": "02",
            "tipoProd": "N",
            "codAlmacen": "101",
            "codArticulo": "001156",
            "articulo": "LAVAX VERDE 300 GRS. X CAJA X 12 UNDS.",
            "codProveedor": "00001",
            "proveedor": "JABONERIA WILSON S.A",
            "codZona": "1021",
            "zona": "LIMA DV",
            "ubigeo": "150101",
            "zonaCodVendedor": "0001",
            "razonSocial": "G.W. YICHANG & CIA S.A.",
            "dirEntrega": "AV.SAN GENARO MZ.B LT.1 LOT.INDUSTRIAL MOLITALIA LOS OLIVOS LIMA-LIMA",
            "ruta": "102",
            "codGiroNegocio": "001",
            "giroNegocio": "DISTRIB HORIZONTAL",
            "ruc": "20100030838",
            "telefono": null,
            "listaPrecio": "024",
            "formaPago": "004",
            "tipoVenta": "O",
            "diaVisita": "5",
            "artIdPres": "00000",
            "codSubLinea": "001",
            "codLinea": "001",
            "dni": null,
            "lineas": "LAVAVAJILLAS",
            "horaEntrega": "001",
            "carro": null,
            "codCanal": "001",
            "artUnidMend": "KG",
            "artUnidMeCom": "CJA",
            "precioUnit": 16.25424,
            "cantidad": 30.0,
            "soles": 487.6272,
            "totalSoles": 575.4001,
            "artUnidPres": 12.0,
            "valorVenta": 487.6272,
            "porcentDcto": 0.0,
            "valorDcto": 0.0,
            "subgenero": "PASTA",
            "marca": "LAVAX",
            "codMarca": "037"
        },
]
```

Y entiendo que es porque includes es un método de array que estoy aplicando sobre un objeto, pero no se que otra forma puedo usar para buscar dentro de mi api las coincidencias que necesito que filtrar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda plis.

Comment: Ayudaría si adjuntas la estructura del objeto `resApi `. ¿Cómo luce este objeto? ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y adjuntarlo? Si no nos dices como luce está dificil que podamos ayudarte a hacer el filtro.

Comment: @JaimeMenendez ya edite la pregunta

Comment: Espero que me estés tomando el pelo. ¿Cómo se supone que con unos puntos en seamos capaces de ayudarte? Por favor, dinos que campos tienen esos objetos. La idea es intentar entender en que campos de lo que te da tu api viene esos nombres y numeros para poder filtrarlos con lo que guardas en tu estado.

Comment: @JaimeMenendez sorry no te tomaba el pelo, pense que solo querias saber como era la estructura, ahi puse un ejemplo del resultado de la api, espero me puedas ayudar :)

Comment: Ok, ahora la cosa va mucho mejor y ya se entiende mucho mejor el problema. Mi pregunta ahora es relacionada con el filtrado y lo que guardas en `filterRow1`. Parecen ser datos aleatorios, veo un nombre y unos numeros y no me queda claro cómo quieres filtrar.  Si es solamente por nombre, echa un vistazo a [este pequeño script que hice](https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3yrqbqqez) . Si por otro lado quieres filtrar por algun otro campo,  ¿Cual seria ese otro campo? ¿O quieres filtrar por cualquier campo que tenga un valor que coincida con lo que tienes en ese array?

Comment: Por ejemplo ese ¿001 y 004 a que se refiere? ¿Al codJefeVenta? ¿Al codSupervisor? ¿A una forma de pago? ¿Deberia devolver todos los objetos que tengan en cualquier campo un 004? Me parece que deberias replantearte lo que guardas en filterRow1, parece información totalmente aleatoria.

Comment: @JaimeMenendez vi el script el problema esta en que no siempre sera vendedor lo que seleccione, ya que ese dato es aleatorio. Te explico mejor, cada key del objeto representa un boton, que al dar click abre una lista de check con todos los values que corresponde a ese key, si el usuario marca un check ese valor se guarda en un stado.

Comment: @JaimeMenendez entonces en el container columna debo mostrar ya filtrado los datos que coincidan con la seleccion del container fila. Agregue una imagen para que lo visualices mejor